# explicit keyword

Tags: c++, explicit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the explicit keyword in C++ mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean)

what does the keyword explicit mean?

Comment: It is a parental warning, indicating there is inappropriate content in the constructor.

Comment: Duplicate of [What does the explicit keyword in C++ mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ constructors that have just one parameter automatically perform implicit type conversion. For example, if you pass an int when the constructor expects a string pointer parameter, the compiler will add the code it must have to convert the int to a string pointer. However, you might not always want this automatic behavior.

You can add explicit to the constructor declaration to prevent implicit conversions. This forces the code to either use a parameter of the correct type, or cast the parameter to the correct type. That is, if the cast is not visibly expressed in code, an error will result.

[explicit (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1y7x448.aspx)